# Wait until webpage is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, php

I've been looking for this for some time but I can't find any ways...

My webpage has a square texture as background and this texture is set on repeat to fill the background.
When someone enters my website for the first time, the texture loads like a puzzle, every square one by one.

Is there a way (any way) to delay the webpage from being displayed until the background loads?

The only thing I found so far is related to hiding and unhiding a div with onclick event.

CSS Code for background:

```
html { 
background: url(/background.jpg) center center fixed; 
background-repeat: repeat;
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: What is the code which loads the background?  Is that an operation happening in JavaScript?

Comment: How are you doing it? Post some code so we can offer some suggestions

Comment: Added the CSS that sets the background.

Comment: Basically, to hide the entire <html> tag until all the elements inside are loaded.

Comment: I don't see how that CSS loads the tiles slowly over time.  Wouldn't the entire background render immediately with this code?

Comment: @David Not really. In special if I'm downloading something and I clean the cache, when I enter, it usually takes like 1-2 seconds for the background to download. During that time, it displays like a chess board...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: I've added a better solution.** It's a lot simpler and more straightforward than my first suggestion.

Solution 2:

You load the background-image in Javascript. Then you set the background-image on the body element (or whatever element you had in mind). Once the image is loaded, you hide a loading (spinner) element that was above the main content.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zmjkuybw/3/) of that.

Solution 1 (**old and more extensive**):

It's a little more creative and extensive, but should get the job done.
Basically, instead of using a CSS background, you use an `HTML5 canvas`. On that canvas you draw your texture with a for loop. Once everything is drawn, you display your page by hiding the *loading* element.

Comment: I'll give it a try in a few minutes.

Comment: I've tried. My page is fully black with only "Loading" on it.

Comment: What javascript library does this require?

Comment: I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined
    at Image.img.onload ((index):108)
img.onload @ (index):108"

Comment: I've updated the solution to a better, simpler one. Also, no JS libraries are used. In the included JSFiddle you can see that the loading element is displayed (for a split-second) before the background-image is set and displayed.